# Crop and scale SVG to PNG using ImageMagick, without pixellation

Tags: imagemagick

I have an SVG with many polygons:

https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/sample-data/current-temps.svg

that looks somewhat like this:

[image]

Cropping this and converting to PNG works fine:

```
convert -crop 100x100+200+150 current-temps.svg /tmp/exhb2.png
```

[image]

Cropping and scaling, however, fails:

```
convert -crop 100x100+200+150 -scale 1000x750 current-temps.svg /tmp/exhb3.png
```

[image]

How do I make ImageMagick "zoom into" the SVG before cropping?

(I realize ImageMagick can only read, not write, the SVG format, but 
it should still be able to do what I want?)

EDIT/SOLVED:

Thanks, robermorales.

```
inkscape -z -e out4.png -w 1000 -h 1000 -a 200:200:400:400 current-temps.svg
```

(for example) worked like a charm.

I also realized that copying the SVG, tweaking the transform line:

```
<g transform="scale(3,3) rotate(-90) translate(-90,180)">
```

and then converting to PNG is another solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try doing scale before crop.

However, doing that using inkscape cli is easier.

Sorry for no links, afk

Answer (score 2):

Don't crop an SVG into PNG.
You can use viewBox to re-define the crop area then convert that SVG into PNG in highest solution as possible. 
Check this post https://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/svg-coordinate-systems/ explain what is viewBox and you will got my idea.

Answer (score 0):

Proper ImageMagick syntax here is to read the input, then crop, then resize. See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#why Though that is not likely the issue. The issue is that -scale will replicated pixels and so make it blocky. You should replace -scale with -resize. That will be smoother, but blurry for the amount of magnification you are requesting.  Try this command:

```
convert current-temps.svg -crop 100x100+200+150 -resize 1000x750 exhb3.png
```