# Cropping SVG to range in Inkscape?

Tags: crop, inkscape

Say I have a range – something like a 400x400 rectangle at 60, 60 – which is dynamically generated by a separate program. I'm wondering how it's possible to crop my document to that range *in the command line*?

Everything I've read has suggested I'd need to add a rectangle to the document, resize the document to that rectangle (resize to selection), and then remove the rectangle.

But I'm having trouble with adding and removing that rectangle. I found the `ToolRect` verb, but I can't seem to find anything related to actually *drawing* that rectangle (or removing it).

So, am I doing this wrong or is there just no way to add (and select) the rectangle using only the command line? Using another program is also fine, but I haven't had much luck with that (I couldn't get the python modules installed for the only possibly helpful thing I found..).

Answer (score 2):

In [this email discussion](http://inkscape.13.x6.nabble.com/CommandLine-passing-parameters-to-verbs-td4964549.html) from 2012, someone said:

> There is no way to pass parameters to verbs (with the current
>   implementation, they don't take parameters by design).

In case they add this capability later, the required verbs to crop the page would be:

1. EditSelectAll
2. SelectionGroup
3. ToolRect (requires parameters, i.e. where to crop)
4. EditSelectAll
5. ObjectSetClipPath
6. FitCanvasToDrawing
7. FileVacuum
8. FileSaveAs (requires a parameter, so that we don't have to overwrite the original)

Since Inkscape can edit any valid SVG, I'd rather look into other available SVG libraries, like [this one for Python](http://www.schoolcoders.com/projects-inkscape).

If you are OK with rasterising your image, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780425/crop-and-scale-svg-to-png-using-imagemagick-without-pixellation). Inkscape unfortunately ignores the --export-area option when exporting to `svg` or `pdf`.

Answer (score 0):

My – admittedly, unsatisfying – solution was to create a separate program to add a viewbox to the SVG text.

The program I made was implemented into a separate part of my project, so I don't have a good command line version, but if you plan on making one yourself, whatever XML editing library you have for your language of choice should be all you need. I used [xmldom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmldom) for Node.js with relative ease.

Answer (score 0):

I'm replying to this old question because I have come across the same problem and have found a different, easy solution.
In the Inkscape, at least in the version 0.92, once you select your elements in the document, go to menu File > Document Properties (or simply Shift+Ctrl+D). On the "Page" tab, under the "Custom size" section look for the button "Resize page to drawing or selection". In my case this button solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good solution for the problem you faced. It's just a bit different from mine, where I wanted to crop to an arbitrary range (not specifically the content in the document), and to do so from the command line (so a Terminal program) instead of manually interacting with Inkscape myself.